# implement the logic of a method() that belong to component A in a component B

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, components, angular5

this my code:

Here you find a function implemented just to add two buttons to a component.

Consider it just as an html code

```
editFonction = "editRole()";  

getActions(Dropup) {
      return '<div class="dropdown ' + (Dropup ? 'dropup' : '') + '">'
          + '<button class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" title="Edit"'
          + '(click)='+this.editFonction+'>'
          + ' <i class="flaticon-edit-1"></i>'
          + '</button>'
          + '<button class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-danger m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" title="Delete">'
          + ' <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>'
          + '</button>';
  }
```

For the first button which is responsible to edit action, I have a click function called `(click)= "editRole()"` . (this code is in component A)

My problem is that this definition of the edit function is located in component A,
and I want to call and implement the logic of this edit function in another component B.

What I do for now:

I created an array called dataFunctions in component A

```
dataFunctions: any[] = [];
```

and in the constructor I just fill it with the name of the function

```
constructor() {
    this.dataFunctions = [this.editFonction];
  }
```

In component B, I define a viewChild :

```
@ViewChild(CustomDataTableComponent) child;
data : any[];
```

and I just recuperate data array values :

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

        this.data = this.child.dataFunctions;
        console.log("output :",this.data);
      }
}
```

I need help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you move the function to a service and call it in both the components from the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass in a reference to component B in component A (say the reference is cmpB).
then in the html you could user `(click)="cmpB.editFonction"`.
eg

```
<componentB #cmpB>
</componentB>
<div (click)="cmpB.editFunction()">
    This is where i want the function to be called
</div>
```

here is an example on stackblitz
[stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqpm4x](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqpm4x)

Comment: a reference like an @Output() cmpB !

Comment: more like some sort of local reference to component B

Comment: can u give me an exp !

Comment: I create in ComponentB :

@Input() cmpB: ComponentB;

 + '(click)='+this.cmpB.editFucntion()+'>'


in ComponentA:

editFucntion(){
        
        this.router.navigate(['/system/doSth']);
    }

Comment: sure!!! lets say we have to components A and B. B has the function you wish to execute and A is where you want that very function to be executed.in the template of A, the simplest case would be` <componentB #cmpB></componentB> <div (click)="cmpB.editFunction()"> This is where i want the function to be called</div>`. this is the simplest use case. you can modify the reference of component B in a way it suits your use case. Good Luck!!

Comment: I do as u said : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'editFunction' of undefined

Comment: are you sure you provided a local reference to start with? can you share a little bit more code or a replication on stackblitz?

Comment: check :



@dummy

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qy72df

 --- files cmpA and B

Comment: I downvote because pass a component by reference make the component depending one from another. It's hard to check or re-utiliser. There are better method using a service

Comment: that completely depends on the use case! it does not make sense to make a service which i will be injecting only once. it would probably be a overhead. However if the service is to be injected multiple number of times, it makes sense. according to the use case i foresee here, it does not feel right. @Eliseo

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqpm4x this is a working example of what i was referring to. just in case someone gets benefited from this